# Error when copying files between drives with API Graph

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive, sharepoint-online, microsoft-graph-teams, microsoft-graph-files

I developed an Azure Function that is copying files from Sharepoint to Teams via Graph API.

In my development Tenant, the Azure Function works fine but when I deploy it in my customer tenant, the file copy fails.

In Azure AD, I registered an application with `Sites.ReadWrite.All`. The AppID/Secrets are used to authenticating the API call.

My call is :

```
POST /drives/b!LbotXZhkxke94OcM0YXrwjR86upNLJdLhSZ_OgDp-T-mtydXTv3sT5A00CrdeZV3/items/01XH5SRTDWNAGSEI66J5GZZXQ6J3NX5KBY/copy
{
  "parentReference": {
    "driveId": "b!mYnVUTiLdES_vJKviIRhfBS6yvSHBD5Bkm3MUTeSBz0DLlyWwF6ORIRel-MFHkAv",
    "id": "01B7MS37LA35AKR6UYIBDJW3QA5DFVCCZJ"
  }
}
```

The response status is `accepted` but the files are not copied.

The `location` response header value is correct, but when I browse to the `location` URL, I have the message "General exception while processing".

The source files exist and the destination drive exists.
If I make this API call in the Graph API Explorer, the files are copied.

Comment: How are you obtaining your token?

Comment: AuthenticationContext context = new AuthenticationContext(ConfigurationHelper.MicrosoftOnlineAuthorityBaseUri, false);
AuthenticationResult authenticationResult = await context.AcquireTokenAsync(ConfigurationHelper.MicrosoftGraphBaseUri, ClientCredential);
return authenticationResult.AccessToken;

Where :
- ClientCredential uses AppID and AppSecrets
- MicrosoftOnlineAuthorityBaseUri = https://login.microsoftonline.com/{TenantId}
- MicrosoftGraphBaseUri = https://graph.microsoft.com/